# Turn asynchronous method to synchronous method in android

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I have some method that is asynchronous so I cannot get response value from it to use in other place (*in this case is Retrofit call back method*). So do we have any way to change the asynchronous method to synchronous method and get values from it?

Comment: Continue the rest of your program in the return method of the asynchronous call

Comment: Would be easier to give an accurate answer if we had code to look at. Using a simple `object.wait()` and `object.notify()` might work.

Comment: @RaduIonescu I declared the global variable to try to get the values out that method but still get null

Comment: @ortis Do it have the same function with CountDownLatch ?

Comment: `I have some method that is asynchronous` - how does this method report it has finished its work?

Comment: @BuiQuangHuy Simpler. Have a look at it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: @marcinj it return values but the value just exist inside that method, cannot get it into outside

Comment: If you want to execute it synchronously you must wait for some condition which indicates that this method finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrofit should have synchronous counterparts to asynchronous calls. Check out [this tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests).

Comment: yes but we have to do everything with response value in onResponse() method. Now I want to get response value outside of it

Comment: Did you even check the link?

Comment: Yes, sorry I had some confuse between ver 1.9 and 2.0. I am using 2.0 so it will return values in onResponse()

Comment: You skipped the part where it discussed about synchronous calls, which is what you're interested in. Instead of calling `enqueue()` and asynchronously consuming the response in onResponse, you call `call.execute()` which is a blocking call that returns the data you need.

Comment: Wait, because it's asynchronous method so maybe it work on Main Thread. I got NetworkOnMainThreadException when I run it

Comment: For update answer of @josephus, the tutorial is ["Retrofit - Synchronous and Asynchronous Requests"](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests)

Answer (score 2):

You just handle result in asynchronous callback then dispatch it to something else to process on business logic, for example a Controller.

Comment: Could you tell more about controller, is it use in Observer Pattern?